# Selenium: Unable to upload files using for loop in Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, file-upload

I want to upload images on a website, I am using `XPath` to do it. Using for loop I have tried, the loop is executed but no action is performed.

Please find my code below:

```
WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver( );
driver.get("https://www.netmeds.com/");
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='carousel-header']/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[3]/button")).click();

for (int i=1;i<5;i++) {

    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='lbl"+i+"']")).sendKeys("C:\\Users\\sys\\Downloads\\1.png");
    System.out.println("upload");
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this code in for loop:

```
for(int i = 1; i < 5; i++){
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='FileUpload" + i + "']")).sendKeys("C:\\a.jpg");
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            System.out.println("File Upload "+ i + "successfully");
        }
```

And it works for me:)

second I can use the `webDriverwait`

Answer (score 2):

**Point 1** - Actually you are doing `sendkeys()` to wrong element i.e. a label. It should be an `<input>` tag with `type=file`  then only you will be able to upload file using `sendkeys()` method

**Point 2** - No need to mention `ImplicitWait` more then one place. If you have mentioned it at one place e.g. after get(URL) then it is applicable for throughout the script. Still If you required some wait then use `ExplicitWait`

Anyway, Use the below code for doing the same what you required :

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

public class Test {

    public static WebDriver driver;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException 
    {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","Resources/chromedriver.exe"); 
        driver = new ChromeDriver();    
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("https://www.netmeds.com");
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@title='Upload Prescription']")).click();
        for(int i=1;i<5;i++)
        {
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='FileUpload"+i+"']")).sendKeys("C:\\LICENCE.jpg");         
            new WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOf(driver.findElement(By.id("loaderContainer"))));
            System.out.println("File Upload "+ i + "Done");
        }

    }
}
```

I've tested at my end and I'm able to upload all 4 images. Let me know if you have any issue with this :)

Comment: is one can not able to perform sendkeys operation using label xpath

Comment: @iamsankalp89, general thing is you can enter text in textbox not in label right ?

Comment: your third line show me error "The method invisibilityOf(WebElement) is undefined for the type ExpectedConditions"  and what loaderContainer in wait

Comment: import this package `import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;`

Comment: already imported this import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;

Comment: I don't think it cause any issue, still i have update the complete example just update your driver location and image file location and try